# Access control modifiers in local classes - why don't they work?

Tags: java, access-control, anonymous-class, local-class

I have a local class declared in a method, whose fields are declared as being private. However, I am still able to access them directly from the body of the enclosing method - why is this?

As a side note, I have declared all of the fields in an anonymous class as being private, but is there actually any benefit in doing this? Could anything access them?

**Edit: code example**

```
public void myMethod() {

    class myException extends SomeOtherException{
        private boolean Bool;

        public Boolean getBool() { return this.Bool; }

        public myException() { //constructor stuff }
    }

    try {
        Thing.setHandler(new HandlingClass() {
            private String myString; //What is the point in making these private?

            ... other methods in anonymous class ...
        }
    ... more code ...
    } catch (myException e) {
        ... e.Bool  //Can be accessed. Why?
    }
}
```

Comment: Making `myString` **private serves no purpose**; the reflection behaviour is slightly different (if a SecurityManager is installed). Mind you can do `new HandlingClass() { ... }.myString`

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it is accessed is because it is accessed in a similar way to the Nested Classes. As per your method the local class attributes are visible, it would have been the same if it was a Nested class.

Here is a fragment from java documentation on Local Classes:

**Accessing Members of an Enclosing Class**

> A local class has access to the members of its enclosing class.
>
> In addition, a local class has access to local variables. However, a
>   local class can only access local variables that are declared final.
>   When a local class accesses a local variable or parameter of the
>   enclosing block, it captures that variable or parameter. For example,
>   the PhoneNumber constructor can access the local variable numberLength
>   because it is declared final; numberLength is a captured variable.
>
> **However, starting in Java SE 8, a local class can access local
>   variables and parameters of the enclosing block that are final or
>   effectively final. A variable or parameter whose value is never
>   changed after it is initialized is effectively final.**

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html